# Android 2 instant run

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[Per Android Studio instant run documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run)

> Code Change
>
> - Change implementation code of an existing instance method or static    method
>
> Instant Run Behavior
>
> - Supported with hot swap: This is the fastest type of swap and makes    changes visible almost instantly. Your application keeps running and
>     a stub method with the new implementation is used the next time the
>     method is called.

However, whenever I do make changes to instance methods or static ones there is always an app restart.  Any solution?

Comment: how do you know that your app is getting re-started? do you see different PID assigned to it by Android?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are seeing an app restart and not an activity restart? By default, activity restart is turned on even for hot swappable changes. You can change this behavior by going to Settings (or Preferences) > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run, and uncheck "Restart activity on code changes".